# How to say "I hope you liked it" or "I hope you found it interesting" as a conclusion for a formal speech?

Tags: grammar, nuances

I am preparing a speech, and would like to finish it by saying 
"I hope you found it interesting" or "I hope you found my speech interesting", 
or similar. However, I am not certain of the different nuances of "hope", nor how to link it with "you liked it". 
This is not the same as saying "Thank you for listening/attention", which will be added to the end as well.
This would be said in a context of a formal speech in a serious context, meant for Japanese teachers and class.

Comment: This would be delivered in the context of a formal, serious speech, in front of a class and Japanese teachers.

Comment: お楽しみいただければ幸いです? It's used for tv programs, music, performances, anything interesting. But I don't know if it can be used for speech.

Answer (score 8):

This doesn't directly answer your question for the exact wording, but a common speech "closing" I've heard is

> ご[清聴]{せい・ちょう}ありがとうございました　→　Thank you very much for your attention

**Note**:  Don't confuse this `[清聴]{せい・ちょう}` with this `[静聴]{せい・ちょう}` that has a slightly different meaning.

Comment: This is for very formal speeches though. For a speech in a class it might be an overkill. ありがとうございました may be more natural in a more informal context

Comment: Yes, this would be in a formal context.

Answer (score 2):

Conversational Japanese by Anne Kaneko offers the following to close a speech of some length (note):

> 今日私の話が少しでも参考になればうれしく思います。ありがとうございました。
>   I hope my speech today has been helpful. Thank you very much.

According to my learner's logic, you could modify this statement to say interesting instead of helpful, by replacing 「参考になれば」with「 面白くなれば」.

When I first read your question, I thought 「面白かったらうれしい」might be safer. As these are concluding remarks, I think the only difference is that where as 「面白くなれば」 emphasizes that for you to be "happy" the audience have to find the talk interesting, 「面白かったら」conveys the message that IF the audience found the talk interesting then you are "happy”.

I should be interested to see comments from others on my two alternative suggestions. Perhaps if you are doing this in a class you have a teacher who could give you feedback you can share here?

Note: for a short speech, this book advises you should just bow and say thank you.

Comment: Thank you Tim! Unfortunately, I can't give any feedback from the teacher, as the speech will be presented as a part of an exam.